# Why glucose and other similar carbohydrates are oxidised fully by HIO4?

Tags: stereochemistry, carbohydrates, organic-oxidation

$\ce{HIO4_{(aq)}}$ requires the vicinal diols to have syn configuration, as it forms a cyclic periodate ester.

[image]

But glucose does not have syn configuration at **C3**, and if you consider cyclic forms of glucose it shouldn't oxidise fully at all because alternate hydroxy groups with **anti configuration** will be unreactive. But it still gets oxidised by $\ce{HIO4}$ to give 5 molecules of methanoic acid, $\ce{HCOOH}$, and one molecule of formaldehyde, $\ce{HCHO}$.
[image]

Comment: I googled "syn anti configuration" and it said "did you mean syn anti conformation". So the search engine has a good point: In the linear form, you can get a conformation where the hydroxyls point the same way.

Comment: "Anti" looks impossible in a Haworth projection. Use a chair conformation of glucose. Anti is slower than syn both with an ~60 deg. dihedral angle. HIO4 can catalyze beta to alpha. Once syn C1-C2 is cleaved in alpha-D-glucose, the ring is gone and there is no anti/syn issue. Or it may all happen in the open form. Look at my answer here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/270/effect-of-periodic-acid-on-cyclohexane-derivatives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glucose can react with $\ce{HIO4}$, which can be understood easily by looking at chair conformation of glucose.

Here is example of a diol, for more information looks at this answer https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/114836/67254

[image]