Why does HIO4 not oxidize carboxylic acids?
I read the mechanism of HIO4 oxidation but and it seemed intuitive to me that it would also oxidize vicinal carboxylic acids into CO2 or when carboxylic acid is next to another functional group oxidize the acid into CO2 and oxidize the other group, for example R-CH(OH)-COOH could be oxidized to RCHO and CO2 but this does not happen. I tried to find an answer anywhere else in the internet but it was always just mentioned that HIO4 doesn't oxidize ethers and carboxylic acids, the reason for ethers is obvious since it's very less reactive but I don't understand why carboxylic acids are not oxidized.

Carboxylic acid isn't an alcohol.

Yes, HIO4 oxidizes vicinal functional groups as long as one of the groups is not an acid functional group, even when the other group is not an acid it does not oxidize it.

This has been answered in depth here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/150653/periodic-acid-oxidation-of-carbonyls  Try and research if periodic acid will oxidize oxalic acid.

@jimchmst , it does explain the mechanism for oxidation of vicinal functional groups, but I couldn't find anything for why the same mechanism can't be used to oxidize carboxylic acid groups vicinal to another oxygen functional group
